# InitializeAsync in MediaCapture doesnt work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await, flashlight

when I do this:

```
try
            {
                MediaCapture mc = new MediaCapture();
                await mc.InitializeAsync();

                if (mc.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.Supported == true)
                {
                    mc.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.Enabled = true;
                    if (mc.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.PowerSupported == true)
                    {
                        mc.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.PowerPercent = 100;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO: Report exception to user
            }
```

I got this error:

**Error 1   The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.**

So I tryed to 'await async mc.InitializeAsync();', then I got this error:

**'Error    1   ; expected'**

What am I doing wrong? Maybe a problem with Library? Thanks

Comment: You need to learn the basics of the `async` keyword in C#.

Comment: You need to add the `async` keyword to your method declaration (which you have omitted from the code in your question) and take a look at the documentation for async/await. If you are confused by the error message you will likely get into a mess later down the line.

Comment: Thanks Daniel Kelley. You answered my question... I should use async in method too :). Thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+async+keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your method like this:

```
public async Task Foo()
{
    //code
    try
        {
            MediaCapture mc = new MediaCapture();
            await mc.InitializeAsync();

            if (mc.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.Supported == true)
            {
                mc.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.Enabled = true;
                if (mc.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.PowerSupported == true)
                {
                    mc.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.PowerPercent = 100;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: Report exception to user
        }

}
```